# Pinning Google Chrome's "Application Shortcuts" to the Windows 7 Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, taskbar

I love the idea behind Google Chromes Application Shortcuts, but they don't integrate well for me into the Windows 7 taskbar.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to have my most used webpages (gmail, calendar, etc) as separate windows, pinned to the Windows 7 taskbar.

I've created some application shortcuts on my desktop, but I've come across the following problems.

- If I open my gmail application shortcut, and then later on open a normal chrome window the new window will also use the gmail icon in the taskbar, even if that window has nothing to do with gmail. (What's weirder, is that this new window then uses a high-res gmail icon, but my actually application shortcut window uses a low-res icon.
- If I pin the application shortcut to the taskbar, then the icon turns into the regular chrome icon.

Any idea's how to fix these issues?  Or are they bugs in google chrome?

Chrome version: 4.0.249.89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new beta release now lets you pin app shortcuts to the taskbar: http://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/ Sweet...

Comment: Awesome!!  Works great! :-D

Answer (score 0):

The best way (so far) is to use FireFox.
Use the Prism Add-on from [addons.mozilla.org / en-US / firefox/ addon / 6665]
It has infact better options to handle the icon appearance ans size.
(the icon in taskbar is handled by Gears, and Google chrome team awaits a change from Gears team.)

For tracking, the bug in Google chrome is discussed at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7028